# Is there a way to write Pi without typing 3.14159... in swift?

Tags: swift, pi

I want to use Pi to calculate the area and circumference of a circle, but without typing like 10 digits of Pi (3.1415926...).
I'm  sure there's a way, 
Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can use `M_PI`. It's a constant given to you for free :)

Comment: You could also declare: `let π = M_PI` and use `π` in your code.

Comment: No problem.

@ABakerSmith Thats a very nice way to do this.

Comment: I prefer M_PI. It's relatively hard for me to type/find [math] Unicode symbols. People who deal with math equations all the time may disagree..

Comment: @user2864740 totally agree, but it looks better. Also on OS X its easy to find it. alt+p gives you a π

Comment: That's strange... What is written in the line? `let π = M_PI` or even more? For me this is working.

Comment: @Frozn Swift [allows many Unicode letters (and symbols)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html) (not just ASCII) to be used as identifiers (eg. variable names). `π` is just a variable (binding) name in the context.

Comment: @user2864740 I know that it works as I said^^ To be a smartass: Here π is no variable, it's a constant ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.pi` or `Double.pi` It's a constant given to you for free :)